# redux-saga with Redux Toolkit - effects do not run

Tags: redux, redux-saga, redux-toolkit

I've got a CRA setup with `@reduxjs/toolkit` and `redux-saga`.

The main saga does run. However, sub-sagas that are meant to be run on `takeEvery` or `fork`, do not seem to run at all.

**Saga:**

```
export function* saga() {
  console.log('main'); //logs

  fork(function* () {
    console.log('fork') //doesn't log
  });
}
```

**Store:**

```
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: state => {
  },
  middleware: defaultMiddleware => defaultMiddleware().concat(sagaMiddleware)
});

sagaMiddleware.run(saga);
```

[Repo link.](https://github.com/Sun-2/saga-effects-dont-run) (Nothing but CRA + Toolkit + redux-saga)

[Related reduxjs/toolkit issue.](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/767)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure you need to `yield` both of those effects for them to do anything:

```
export function* saga() {
  console.log('main'); //runs

  yield takeEvery('*', function*() {
    console.log('takeEvery') //doesnt run
  })

  yield fork(function* () {
    console.log('gen') // doesnt run
  });
}
```

I think the `yield takeEvery` might also "block" the saga from continuing on to reach the fork?  Not sure on the saga semantics here.

Comment: Damn, I forgot about that. And you're right, `takeEvery` does block.